# Unable to access infinispan management interface over edge-terminated SSL OpenShift route

Tags: openshift, wildfly, infinispan

I am building an Infinispan cluster on OpenShift based off the documentation found [here](http://blog.infinispan.org/2016/08/running-infinispan-cluster-on-openshift.html). I am trying to access the Management interface through the exposed 9990 port. I am using version 9.1.3.Final.

When I set the route to be HTTP to the 9990 management port, the management interface appears correctly. When I set the route to be secured with Edge termination, the interface errors out with the following error message.

[image: Error message]

Looking at the requests on the network, it appears I get a 403 somewhere in the authentication flow:

[image: request flow]

Is there something I should do differently to configure the Infinispan server to accept this traffic? I am using the default cloud configuration with the Kubernetes jgroups stack.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting an `allowed-origins` field on the `cloud.xml` within the `management-interface` tag:

```
<management-interfaces>
    <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true" allowed-origins="https://infinispan-app-management-myproject.192.168.0.10.xip.io">
        <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
    </http-interface>
</management-interfaces>
```